# Getting Joomla User Group Id to variable

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, foreach, joomla3.0

Joomla 3.0

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->get('groups');

foreach($groups as $group) {
echo $group;
}
```

This was an answer @lodder gave a while back, in regards to getting the user group id. My issue is that the user is in multiple groups. I need to differentiates between using the second group that gets ran. For example.

User 1 = Group 2 & 11

User 2 = Group 2 & 14

User 3 = Group 2 & 16

How can i get this into a variable I can use. I'm having a duhhh....moment...

I feel like this should actually be called by using something more like this

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->get('groups');

$usergrouptwo = $groups[2];
```

Then again, I have more experiance with for() loops than foreach loops.

I need to simply be able to use a variable outside of the foreach() like this

```
If ($finalgroupid = 11) Do X
If ($finalgroupid = 14) Do Y
If ($finalgroupid = 16) Do Z
```

Again, I'm sure their is something stupid I'm forgetting.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user groups will be returned with the index as the id of the group.

```
array (size=2)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
  12 => string '12' (length=2)
```

So, you need to check against the second key.

```
$keys = array_keys($groups);
$secondgroup = $keys[1];

switch($secondgroup){

     case 12:
         //do something
         break;

     default:
         break;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Derek-s I knew their was a simple way to do it. This is similar to how regular FOR() loops are solved using $i. 
I'm going to look more into "array_key" document so I can brush up. Have a good one!